# Data not showing in my another Html table after submitting. I am using spring mvc with thymeleaf, what might be the reason

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I added thymeleaf object and variable expressions in html and written @Getmapping and @postmapping methods and separate pojo class. after submitting the data using form.html file it going to another grades.html file but data is not showing what might be the issue.

```js
controller program


@Controller
public class piperscontroller {


  List<piedpiper> addGrades= new ArrayList<>();

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String submitForm(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("grades",new piedpiper());

    return "form";

  }
        @PostMapping("/handleSubmit")
        public String grademeth(piedpiper grades){
            addGrades.add(grades);
            return "redirect:/grades";

        }

        @GetMapping("/grades")
        public String finalButton(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("grades",addGrades);
            return "grades";
        }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <link th:href="@{/css/form.css} " rel="stylesheet">
  </head>    
  <body>
    <div class="topnav">
      <a>Form</a>
      <a>Grades</a>
    </div>   
    <div class="container">
      <h2> Grade Portal </h2>
      <form method="post" th:object="${grades}" th:action="@{/handleSubmit}"> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" th:field="*{name}" >
        <input type="text" placeholder="Score"  th:field="*{score}">  
        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject"  th:field="*{subject}">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "data is not showing" is very vague. Can you elaborate where you want to have data showing?

Comment: Into the next html page where it is redirected in postmapping

Comment: What is `piedpiper`, what does it look like?

Comment: it is a pojo class with variables name, score, subject and setters,getters and constructor with fields and empty contructor

Comment: Can you try adding `@ModelAttribute("grades")` ? E.g. `public String grademeth(@ModelAttribute("grades") piedpiper grades)`